# Induction: If $A, B_{1}, B_{2}, \ldots, B_{n}$ are any sets, then $\forall n \geqslant 2$.

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I have an induction homework. Is my result correct? I think I've just overthinking in this problem. Am I on the right track or is my conclusion correct? Thank you.

Use weak induction to show that if $A, B_{1}, B_{2}, \ldots, B_{n}$ are any sets, then $\forall n \geqslant 2$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
A \cup\left(B_{1} \cap B_{2} \cap \ldots \cap B_{n}\right)=&\left(A \cup B_{1}\right) \cap\left(A \cup B_{2}\right) \cap \ldots \cap\left(A \cup B_{n}\right) .
\end{aligned}
$$

**Basic Step:**

Taking $n=2$, then we have:

$$
A \cup\left(B_{1} \cap B_{2}\right)=\left(A \cup B_{1}\right) \cap\left(A \cup B_{2}\right)
$$
For this we have to prove that:

$A \cup\left(B_{1} \cap B_{2}\right) \subseteq\left(A \cup B_{1}\right) \cap\left(A \cup B_{2}\right)$ and $\left(A \cup B_{1}\right) \cap\left(A \cup B_{2}\right) \subseteq A \cup\left(B_{1} \cap B_{2}\right)$

Now let:

\begin{aligned}
&x \in A \cup\left(B_{1} \cap B_{2}\right) \\
&\Rightarrow x \in A \text { or } x \in B_{1} \cap B_{2} \\
&\Rightarrow x \in A \text { or }\left(x \in B_{1} \;and\; B_{2}\right)
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
\text{I:}\\
&\Rightarrow\left(x \in A \operatorname{or} x \in B_{1}) \text { and } \left(x \in A \text { or } x \in B_{2}\right)\right. \\
&\Rightarrow x \in A \cup B_{1} \text { and } x \in A \cup B_{2} \\
&\Rightarrow x \in\left(A \cup B_{1}\right) \cap\left(A \cup B_{2}\right) \\
&\Rightarrow A \cup \left(B_{1} \cap B_{2}\right) \subseteq\left(A \cup B_{1}\right) \cap\left(A \cup B_{2}\right)
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
\text{II:}\\
& x \in\left(A \cup B_{1}\right) \cap\left(A \cup B_{2}\right) \\
\Rightarrow & x \in A \cup B_{1} \text { and } x \in A \cup B_{2} \\
\Rightarrow &\left(x \in A \text { or } x \in B_{1}\right) \text { and }\left(x \in A \text { or } x \in B_{2}\right) \\
\Rightarrow & x \in A \text { or }\left(x \in B_{1} \text { and } x \in B_{2}\right) \\
\Rightarrow & x \in A \text { or }\left(x \in B_{1} \cap B_{2}\right) \\
\Rightarrow & x \in A \cup\left(B_{1} \cap B_{2}\right) \\
\Rightarrow & \left(A \cup B_{1}\right) \cap\left(A \cup B_{2}\right) \subseteq A \cup\left(B_{1} \cap B_{2}\right)
\end{aligned}

By $I$ and $II$ we have:
\begin{aligned}
\text{III:}\\
& A \cup\left(B_{1} \cap B_{2}\right)=\left(A \cup B_{1}\right) \cap\left(A \cup B_{2}\right)
\end{aligned}

Suppose $III$ hold for $n-1$. So now we have:

\begin{aligned}
\text{IV:}\\
&
A \cup\left(B_{1} \cap B_{2} \cap \ldots \cap B_{n-1}\right)=\left(A \cup B_{1}) \cap\left(A \cup B_{2}\right) \cap\right. 
\ldots \cap\left(A \cup B_{n-1}\right)
\end{aligned}

Let $B_{1} \cap B_{2} \cap \cdots \cap B_{n-1}=x$

Now for $n>=2$:

$A \cup\left(B_{1} \cap B_{2} \cap \ldots \cap B_{n-1} \cap B_{n}\right)=A \cup\left(x \cap B_{n}\right)$

\begin{gathered}
=(A \cup x) \cap\left(A \cup B_{n}\right)(\text{we have for } n=2) \\
\Rightarrow A \cup\left(B_{1} \cap B_{2} \cap \dotsm \cap B_{n}\right)=(A \cup x) \cap\left(A \cup B_{n}\right) \\
=\left(A \cup\left(B_{1} \cap B_{2} \cap \ldots\cap B_{n-1}\right)\right) \cap\left(A \cup B_{n}\right) \text { (by our assumplion) } \\
=\left(A \cup B_{1}\right) \cap\left(A \cup B_{2}\right) A \ldots \cap\left(A \cup B_{n-1}\right) \cap 
\left(A \cup B_{n}\right)\;(\text{by IV}) \\
\Rightarrow A \cup\left(B_{1} \cap B_{2} \cap \ldots \cap B n\right)=\left(A \cup B_{1}\right) \cap\left(A \cup B_{2}\right) \cap 
\ldots \cap\left(A \cup B_{n}\right)
\end{gathered}

Comment: Notice it's also true for $n=1$, and the base case $n=1$ is trivial. So it's easier to show by induction it holds for all $n \geq 1$, which certainly implies it's true for all $n \geq 2$.

Comment: In fact, unions also distribute over infinite intersections (and likewise, intersections distribute over finite and infinite unions).

Comment: Since you've worked so hard on the assignment-mandated proof strategy, you deserve an alternative proof in case it interests you:$$\begin{align}x\in A\cup\bigcap_iB_i&\iff x\in A\lor x\in\bigcap_i B_i\\&\iff x\in A\lor\forall i(x\in B_i)\\&\iff\forall i(x\in A\lor x\in B_i)\\&\iff\forall i(x\in A\cup B_i)\\&\iff x\in\bigcap_i A\cup B_i.\end{align}$$@GeoffreyTrang already alluded to its not restricting us to finitely many values of $i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution seems fine to me but I will try to reduce the notation a bit:

$\color{Red}{\text{Caso }n=2:}$
\begin{align*}
x\in A \cup\left(B_{1} \cap B_{2}\right)&\Leftrightarrow x\in A\vee(x\in B_1\wedge x\in B_2)\Leftrightarrow (x\in A\vee x\in B_1)\wedge (x\in A\vee x\in B_2)\\
&\Leftrightarrow x\in (A\cup B_1)\cap (A\cup B_2)
\end{align*}

$\color{Red}{\text{Caso }n=k:}$ Suppose that is hold for $k−1$. So now we have
$\displaystyle A\cup \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k-1}B_i\right)=\bigcap_{i=1}^{k-1}(A\cup B_i)$. Then

\begin{align*}
x\in A\cup \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}B_i\right)&\Leftrightarrow x\in A\cup \left(B_k\cap\bigcap_{i=1}^{k-1}B_i\right) \Leftrightarrow x\in (A\cup B_k)\cap \left(A\cup \bigcap_{i=1}^{k-1}B_i\right)\\
&\Leftrightarrow x\in(A\cup B_k)\cap \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k-1}(A\cup B_i)\right)\\
&\Leftrightarrow x\in \bigcap_{i=1}^{k}(A\cup B_i)
\end{align*}